# No class def found java

Tags: java, http, amazon-s3

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext
 at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:119)
 at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:103)
 at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:362)
 at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:344)
 at Gethtml_fromS3.main(Gethtml_fromS3.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
 ... 5 more
```

Can any one give me a solution for the above error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

Please check if you have httpcore jar.  I got rid of this error, after adding httpcore-4.2.jar to my lib.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to pinpoint  the exact reason why your application raises this exception, but a few common pointers that might help you.

The exception is raised when you are using a class in your code that isn't available when it runs. In this case, it seems you are unable to use org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext. Most likely, you created an application that does include the Amazon AWS jar, but lacks the Apache HTTPClient jar.

If you used gradle/maven to create your application, include it in your dependencies. It it's a plain Java program, ensure the required JARs are available in your classpath (e.g. the same place as you currently have the Amazon jar located).